# iphone: How to remove white strip from bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I changed the background color to black.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: (10.0/255) green: (10.0/255) blue: (10.0/255) alpha: 1.0];
}
```

but both in device or Emulator it shows a white strip in the end. How to get rid of this ... please help

[image]

Comment: The problem is in the way you are attaching the view to the window or the parent view. Please provide more code.

Comment: check the view's start position + frame size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this happen you probably are adding a subview that are white, or your view is with the wrong frame size, or your frame is with the wrong initial point.

Try this code to change the view frame to be equal to your device frame:

```
[self.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the view's `y` origin position to 20.0f .

I hope you have the nib file for the view. Check the frame position of the view. If the origin y is 0, then height should be 480.0f. Else if the origin y is 20.0f, then height should be 460.0f .